# What is the difference between these statements in a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I am still learning about generics and have a question. Say you had this generic class:

```
public class Test<T> {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        Test<String> t2 = new Test<String>();
        Test t3 = new Test<String>();
    }
}
```

All the statements compile but I don't really know what makes them different. Can anyone give me a brief explanation on those three statements.

Comment: Almost true. The other two only ad warnings, but not real compile error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Test t1 = new Test();
```

Here you are using a **Raw type**. i.e., not passing an `Type argument` for your `generic clas`s.

Compiler should give you a warning here

> Test is a raw type. References to generic type Test should be 
>      parameterized

```
    Test<String> t2 = new Test<String>();
```

here you are using generics. passing String as a `type argument` to your `generic class`.

```
    Test t3 = new Test<String>();
```

compiler should also give you a warning here too :

> - Test is a raw type. References to generic type Test should be       parameterized

same as your first case, but you are using parameterized type while invoking the constructor.

There is also another class which works fine in +java 7 versions.

```
    Test<String> t4 = new Test<>();
```

No compiler warning here if you use + java 7 due to **Type Inference**

In this case due to introduction of `type inference` generic type is inferred, thus you don't need to provide the generic type during constructor invokation.

Comment: We should also add that the original question missed two combinations: `Test<String> t4 = new Test()`, which will not compile because it attempts to assign a reference of a raw type to one of a generic type; and `Test<String> t5 = new Test<>()`, which compiles using the new "diamond operator" in Java 7.

Comment: +1 and since java 7 you can also write Test<String> t4 = new Test<>(); which is equivalent to the t2 declaration...

Comment: @yshavit  and pgras just added it guys :)

Answer (score 3):

Generics give you compile-time type checks.

It helps to add examples of what you can/can't do with your items (I've changed `Test` to `ArrayList` for ease of examples):

```
    ArrayList t1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> t2 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList t3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    // First list can have ANYTHING added to it
    // Compiler won't check because no generics
    t1.add(new Integer("7"));
    t1.add("Hello");

    // Second list can only have Strings added to it
    // Compiler will check and throw compile error for anything else
    t2.add(new Integer("7"));   // doesn't compile
    t2.add("Hello");

    // Third list is interesting...
    // Again, can have ANYTHING added to it
    // This is because generics (in Java...) are swapped out at COMPILE time
    //   rather than RUNTIME. The compiler can see that the actual type is just
    //   plain ArrayList
    // If you like, it's similar to doing: 
    //   Object o = (String) new Object(); 
    // The net-effect is everything reduced back to Object
    t3.add(new Integer("7"));  // fine
    t3.add("Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

They all actually create **identical** objects. The only difference will be how they are treated syntactically in the rest of the code.

`t1` and `t3` will be treated in exactly the same way because they are the same type - they will be treated as an object with class `Test`, nothing more.

`t2` will be treated more rigorously in terms of type checking. If some opportunity presents itself for the compiler to make use of its generic `<String>` quality then that quality will also be required to match.